# Installing iPython Notebook - opening a $HOME file from editor

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to install ipython notebook based on some instructions. However, while I tried to execute this 'In your favorite editor, open the file $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py', I can't really open a file from TextWrangler. I am not familiar with this. Could anyone help me out there? Thank you very much!!

Comment: What instructions are you following? The IPython Notebook became the Jupyter Notebook, which keeps config files under `~/.jupyter/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's not there? you can create it first, in Mac's terminal

`touch $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py`

and then open it in TextWranggler

`open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app $HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py`